# rosserial_arduino helloworld error

Tags: ros, arduino, ros-lib, ros-fuerte, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
could use some help to make rosserial_arduino work and have an arduino work with ROS for me. Have followed all the instructions, tested it on 2 different Arduino's but got the error below and I am out of ideas what I might be doing wrong. I am working on Fuerte, did get Fuerte branch from github (kforce giving errors), was able to rosbuild without errors, have copied ros_lib to sketchbook as instructed. But when compiling the helloword sketch I keep getting error below. Any clues? Thanks

```
  In file included from HelloWorld.pde:6:
/home/turtelbot/sketchbook/libraries/ros_lib/ros.h:38:29: error: ros/node_handle.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /home/turtelbot/sketchbook/libraries/ros_lib/ros.h:39,
                 from HelloWorld.pde:6:
/home/turtelbot/sketchbook/libraries/ros_lib/ArduinoHardware.h:38:22: error: WProgram.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /home/turtelbot/sketchbook/libraries/ros_lib/ros.h:39,
                 from HelloWorld.pde:6:
/home/turtelbot/sketchbook/libraries/ros_lib/ArduinoHardware.h: In member function ‘long unsigned int ArduinoHardware::time()’:
/home/turtelbot/sketchbook/libraries/ros_lib/ArduinoHardware.h:73: error: ‘millis’ was not declared in this scope
In file included from HelloWorld.pde:6:
/home/turtelbot/sketchbook/libraries/ros_lib/ros.h: At global scope:
/home/turtelbot/sketchbook/libraries/ros_lib/ros.h:49: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
HelloWorld:9: error: ‘NodeHandle’ in namespace ‘ros’ does not name a type
HelloWorld:11: error: ‘std_msgs’ has not been declared
HelloWorld:11: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘str_msg’
HelloWorld:12: error: ‘Publisher’ in namespace ‘ros’ does not name a type
HelloWorld.pde: In function ‘void setup()’:
HelloWorld:18: error: ‘nh’ was not declared in this scope
HelloWorld:19: error: ‘chatter’ was not declared in this scope
HelloWorld.pde: In function ‘void loop()’:
HelloWorld:24: error: ‘str_msg’ was not declared in this scope
HelloWorld:25: error: ‘chatter’ was not declared in this scope
HelloWorld:26: error: ‘nh’ was not declared in this scope
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/125761/rosserial_arduino-helloworld-error/) by [Charel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3796/charel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2014-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I gave up on Fuerte. Have it now running, using Groovy with Catkin. Now it works for both my Arduino Uno and Arduino ATMega.

---

Originally posted by [Charel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3796/charel/) with karma: 81 on 2014-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1